# Problem working with python/pygame

Tags: python, ipython

I encounter this problem almost always when i am working on a python-pygame project. Every second time when i evaluate the whole buffer with `C-c C-c` or with `C-c C-l` the pygame window open for a very short time and then every thing crashes including the python interpreter, and i get this error message:

```
Process Python segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Does anyone know what the reason is and how can i fix it? I am on ubuntu 16.04 and using the default python-mode of emacs24.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a problem with python-mode  but with your python instance. 
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13654489/1748672) goes into more detail, but it boils down to something has crashed. From the description you've given it sounds like your python instance is the crashing element. Double check that your python installed right. Considering that it is ubuntu, it should be fine. Next try reinstalling pygame. If your code is using a c compiled module make sure that it compiled right, and reinstall it.
Sorry that this is rather vague answer, if you provide code for evaluation I can go more in depth.